# ObjC Register App for special String formats

Tags: ios, objective-c

is there a possibility to register my own app for special string formats
similar to file extension registration?

Example: phone numbers in mail or safari browser are recognized and referenced with
the "Phone" app.

thx
bobbyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
in your delegate implemented 'applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url received: %@", url);


    return YES;
}
```

after you implemented that , open safari and type in the URL field :

**YourAppName://message**

Original Apple's Doc - [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)